# Libgdx - how to rotate the emmition trail of a 3d particle

Tags: java, libgdx, particles, particle-system

I have encountered a problem while using libGDX 3D particles.

I wanted to change the direction the particles are being emitted.

I tried

```
effect.rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
```

when my particle starts at point (1, 0, 1), and the emission goes towards -x;
which only rotated the spawn point of the particles but NOT the direction of the emitted particles

I also tried the matrix4 way

```
targetMatrix.idt();
targetMatrix.setToRotation(...);
```

and

```
targetMatrix.rotate(...);
```

however none of them did what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too trying to make a simple fireball effect. The rotation or any transform done to the effect will not do what you wan't, don't ask me why it's just one of the strange things about the 3d-particle system.

What you can do is get the emitters for the effect and manually change the theta and phi angles. I do not have access to my code right now but can give you an example if needed. But once you find those two angles you can make the particles emit in any direction you wan't.

This is how I initialize my fireball effect. The theta and phi angles could be changed each tick and it would fix your problem.

```
effect = Assets.assetManager.get(skillInfo.skillEffect, ParticleEffect.class).copy();

    for (int i = 0; i < effect.getControllers().size; i++) {

        effect.getControllers().get(i).attached = skillInfo.attached;

        if (skillInfo.attached && effect.getControllers().get(i).findInfluencer(DynamicsInfluencer.class) != null) {
            // Gdx.app.log("INFO", "FOUND DI");
            DynamicsInfluencer di = effect.getControllers().get(i).findInfluencer(DynamicsInfluencer.class);
            DynamicsModifier dm;
            for (int j = 0; j < di.velocities.size; j++) {

                dm = (DynamicsModifier) di.velocities.get(j);

                if (dm instanceof PolarAcceleration) {
                    // horizontal +/- spread
                    float phiSpread = Math.abs(((PolarAcceleration) dm).phiValue.getHighMax()
                            - ((PolarAcceleration) dm).phiValue.getHighMin());
                    ((PolarAcceleration) dm).phiValue.setHigh(90 - 0.5f * phiSpread, 90 + 0.5f * phiSpread);

                    // change to acc in opposite direction of movement
                    // direction
                    float angle = getAngleAroundY(direction);
                    float thetaSpread = Math.abs(((PolarAcceleration) dm).thetaValue.getHighMax()
                            - ((PolarAcceleration) dm).thetaValue.getHighMin());
                    ((PolarAcceleration) dm).thetaValue.setHigh(angle - thetaSpread * 0.5f, angle + thetaSpread * 0.5f); // rotation
                                                                                                                            // around
                                                                                                                            // y-axis

                } else {
                    // Gdx.app.log("INFO", "NO polar acc for: " +
                    // skillInfo.name);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Gdx.app.log("INFO", "no DI");
        }
```

Where :

```
                    ((PolarAcceleration) dm).phiValue.setHigh(90 - 0.5f * phiSpread, 90 + 0.5f * phiSpread);


                    ((PolarAcceleration) dm).thetaValue.setHigh(angle - thetaSpread * 0.5f, angle + thetaSpread * 0.5f);
```

Would be the part interesting for you.

EDIT: See below for the code that is relevant for setting the theta and phi angles in code

```
 DynamicsInfluencer di = effect.getControllers().get(i).findInfluencer(DynamicsInfluencer.class);
        DynamicsModifier dm;
        for (int j = 0; j < di.velocities.size; j++) {

            dm = (DynamicsModifier) di.velocities.get(j);

                ((PolarAcceleration) dm).phiValue.setHigh(90 - 0.5f * phiSpread, 90 + 0.5f * phiSpread);

                ((PolarAcceleration) dm).thetaValue.setHigh(angle - thetaSpread * 0.5f, angle + thetaSpread * 0.5f);
        }
```

Comment: Please give me an example, I do not understand what do you mean by "manually change the theta and phi angles." Do you mean change them in the particle editor and then create many separate files for each angle. Or is there a way to change them in code?

Comment: I mean change them in your code, do it every tick in an update method for example. You can find the phi and theta in the dynamics influencer.

Comment: What is "skillInfo", and what is "Assets.assetsManager"? I do not understand what are they?

Comment: That is because I just ripped it from my code that does more than just edits the effect, just ignore it. Added an edit with the relevant code for the angles of the effect

Comment: getAngleAroundY(direction) what is this?

Comment: That is just a helper method that get the angle I want to use. Just ignore it and instead look at the code below the EDIT: